# Execute code in quarto document from R Script

Tags: r, quarto

Got a particular problem, for work, I needed to create a quarto doc with documentation. However, I do not want to recreate all this work in a separate script.  I want to run the code in the quarto doc (similar to the hotkey ctrl + alt + R), but from a separate R script.

1. Create new .qmd and add a code chunk with results stored as an object

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
editor: visual
---

```{r}
added <- 1+2+3
```
````

2. In a separate script, run the code from the qmd, without rendering the doc, just run all code chunks in order to generate the stored objects

Best result would be to run all the code chunks in order, which I think used to be possible with the `quarto_run()` function, but not certain.

In this case, I do not really care about rendering an html, pdf, or docx, only about executing the code from a separate R script.  Any help would be appreciated

I am running quarto version ‘1.3.433’

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: It is not a precise reprex, since there was no error to speak of, but rather a process I would like to perform, but not sure exactly how to conduct the work

Comment: Only method I am aware of so far is to open the quarto doc, use the hotkey ctrl + alt + R, and run all code chunks, then move to an external script to evaluate the newly created objects from that script....would be nice to not need to jump from the quarto doc to the separate script